# ALSA combine mic inputs and speaker outputs for Skype

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, alsa

I'm trying to merge two mic inputs and two outputs to use in Skype, Linux CentOS7
I know I can do it with a hardware mixer, but I want to try to do it by software.

Just finished a bash script to combine outputs, and it's running well. I'm getting crazy trying to combine inputs.

This is the name of the two usb soundcard mic inputs:
alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-mono
alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00-Device_1.analog-mono

I found a lot of on pacmd / pactl info, and tested a lot of commands, but nothing works.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getOutputs {
    index=""
    name=""
    #declare -A sinks_list

    # Get dirty sinks list
    raw_sinks=`pacmd list-sinks`

    # Parse the sources list
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        #Check if index and name are populated
        if [ -n "$index" ] && [ -n "$name" ]
        then
            sinks_list[$index]=$name
            index=""
            name=""
        fi
        # Get indexs and index number
        if grep -q index: <<<"$line"
        then
            index=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
        fi
        # Get sound card output name and remove other than c-media soundcards
        if grep -q name: <<<"$line" && grep -q stereo <<<"$line" && grep -q C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device <<<"$line"
        then
            name=$(echo "$line" | sed -e "s/name://" | sed 's|[<>,]||g'| tr -d '[:space:]')
        fi
    done <<< "$raw_sinks"
}

function getInputs {
    index=""
    name=""
    #declare -A sources_list

    # Get dirty sources list
    raw_sources=`pacmd list-sources`

    # Parse the sources list
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        #Check if index and name are populated
        if [ -n "$index" ] && [ -n "$name" ]
        then
            sources_list[$index]=$name
            index=""
            name=""            
        fi
        # Get indexs and index number
        if grep -q index: <<<"$line"
        then
            index=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
        fi
        # Get sound card output name and remove other than c-media soundcards
        if grep -q name: <<<"$line" && grep -q mono <<<"$line" && grep -q C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device <<<"$line"
        then
            name=$(echo "$line" | sed -e "s/name://" | sed 's|[<>,]||g'| tr -d '[:space:]')
        fi
    done <<< "$raw_sources"
}

function combineOutputs {
    soundcard_names=""

    for K in "${!sinks_list[@]}"; 
    do
        # Set device default volume
        pacmd set-sink-volume ${sinks_list[$K]} 65536
        soundcard_names+=${sinks_list[$K]},
    done

    pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=MySink slaves=$soundcard_names

    # Set default volume
    pacmd set-sink-volume MySink 65536

    # Set as default source
    pacmd set-default-sink MySink
}

function combineInputs {
    # Create a null sink to merge signals
    pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MyLoopSink

    # One by one add mics to the null sink
    for K in "${!sources_list[@]}"; 
    do
        pactl load-module module-loopback source=$K sink=MyLoopSink
    done

    pacmd set-default-source MyLoopSink.monitor
    # Create a virtual source. Note: using uplink_sink=MyLoopSink removes all the devices
    pacmd load-module module-virtual-source source_name=loop_source

    # Set as default source
    pacmd set-default-source loop_source
}

# First restart pulseaudio to get sure we are working with a clean configuration
pulseaudio -k
sleep 10

# Combine Inputs
declare -A sources_list
getInputs
# Loop through array values
echo "Soundcard's inputs:"
for K in "${!sources_list[@]}"; 
do
    echo $K --- ${sources_list[$K]}
done
combineInputs

# Combine Outputs
declare -A sinks_list
getOutputs
# Loop through array values
echo "Soundcard's outputs:"
for K in "${!sinks_list[@]}"; 
do
    echo $K --- ${sinks_list[$K]}
done
combineOutputs
```

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. Just added the script instead of the short example.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) audio server with software mixers and many other tools available. I work with a group using [IDJC](http://idjc.sourceforge.net/tour_main.html) to mix audio (including skype callers) to broadcast on internet with icecast. Graphical patchbay in JACK to get audio connections right isn't a necessity, but makes it much easier and quicker

`pactl` commands should be preferred over for script control of Pulseaudio, but not all `pacmd` commands have an equivalent in `pactl`

`pacmd` command runs in a terminal shell and does not work in scripts with a direct command

Command will work in script if used with `echo` command. This is one of the commands i use in a script to manage Pulseaudio to JACK connections:

```
echo "set-default-sink voip2jack" |pacmd
```